# GCDAsyncUdpSocket + Bonjour? (bynamic udp port)

Tags: ios, bonjour, gcdasyncsocket

I'm using `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` for my project, I can bind a port this way, **(Server part)**

```
[udpSocket bindToPort:45678 error:&error];
```

But I don't want to give a static port number for this. How to get available free ports for UDP communication ? I am going to publish it as a service using Bonjour ? Am I on the right track ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this well-done tutorial -- I did and have a product on the store that uses Bonjour because of this tutorial!

[Tutorial: Networking and Bonjour on iPhone](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/)

Comment: Website seems to be down.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150626055648/http://www.whatsoniphone.com/blog/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/